# Shell output from one command as input to other

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script, sed, grep

I am trying to automate [Forever JS to keep my dev server running](https://www.npmjs.com/package/forever) and for that I need to check and stop the forever process to start another one. By running

```
sudo forever list
```

I get the following output:

> ```
> info:    Forever processes running
> data:        uid  command         script forever pid   id logfile                        uptime       
> data:    [0] 0NQH /usr/bin/nodejs app.js 17047   17049    /home/ubuntu/.forever/0NQH.log 0:2:4:58.594
> ```

From the above output I need the **pid** which is **17049** currently and feed it to the next command like so:

```
sudo forever stop {{pidfromabove}}
```

To accomplish this, in my script I've tried out many things, mainly trying to find the two strings between **app.js** and **/home** but for some reason it keeps printing the whole line. I've tried different combinations of sed and awk. How do I get the pid from the above to feed to the next `stop` command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a use case for `awk`. If you're sure that the output format is stable so that the PID you're interested in is always the 7th element of the line, this will print the PID for `app.js`:

```
sudo forever list | awk '/app\.js/ { print $7 }'
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue you encounter may be because the output is on stderr, not on stdout.
If this is the case, you can try:

```
sudo forever list 2>&1 | sed 's/.*app.js [0-9]* \([0-9]*\) /\1/'
```

It should answer just the second pid.

Then you could do:

```
sudo forever stop `sudo forever list 2>&1 | sed 's/.*app.js [0-9]* \([0-9]*\) /\1/'`
```

Comment: Sorry the first command instead of printing just the pid number prints the whole output like
info:    Forever processes running
data:        uid  command         script forever pid   id logfile                        uptime        
 17049    /home/ubuntu/.forever/0NQH.log 0:2:24:45.113

Comment: My mistake, I didn't see that there were two lines ! You would need a grep in addition to the sed.
The command is actually working on the data line (only 17049 printed) but not on the info line (fully printed)